# oracle subquery : error not getting resolved

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

I have two tables:

one is ATM and other is HOST(structure is same)
There is data in ATM which isn't present in HOST. I want to sync the tables, i.e., whatever data is missing from HOST and present in ATM , must be returned.

My solution:

```
SELECT HOST.TRANS_ID WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM ATM WHERE ATM.TRANS_ID = HOST.TRANS_ID)
```

still i am getting an error!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to address the error you are getting, your SQL is invalid. To perform the query you are trying to write you would need a `FROM` clause in your outer query, it should read:

```
SELECT HOST.TRANS_ID 
  FROM host
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT * 
         FROM ATM 
        WHERE ATM.TRANS_ID = HOST.TRANS_ID);
```

However, your query will not return the data you need as by your definition ("data is missing from host"), if the data does not exist in `HOST`, how can you select it?

I would be inclined to use the following query to solve your issue:

```
SELECT trans_id
  FROM atm
  LEFT OUTER JOIN host
 USING trans_id
  WHERE host.rowid IS NULL;
```

In this query, we perform an outer join returning all rows from `ATM` (as it hold rows not present in `HOST`). The rows in HOST that are not present will return a NULL rowid so by selecting all `TRANS_ID` values where the `HOST` rowid is null will show you the `ATM` values that have no corresponding `HOST` value which I believe is what you are wanting.

HTH